# remove an item from combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

I want binding a combobox from all 4 letters words in a text file in my D: drive, so I wrote a class and declare a name and value :

```
public class Words
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In my form use this codes to bind all 4 letters to my combobox:

```
string fileLoc = @"d:\Words.txt";
string AllWords = "";
var word4 = new List<Words>();
if (File.Exists(fileLoc))
{
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileLoc))
    {
        AllWords = tr.ReadLine();
    }
}
string[] words = AllWords.Split('-');
foreach (string word in words)
{
     if (word.Length == 4)
     {
        word4.Add(new Words() { Name = word, Value = word });
     }
}
this.comboBox4.DataSource = word4;
this.comboBox4.DisplayMember = "Name";
this.comboBox4.ValueMember = "Value";
this.comboBox4.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

now, I want remove word when select it and click a button.just remove from combobox not remove from text file.after reload the form must all words show on combo again.
becuase I use many combo for all length of words,and in diffrent condition just one of combos are shown to user,for access and remove the item I wrote this method:

```
 ComboBox combo = this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>().First(K => K.Visible);
 combo.Items.Remove(combo.SelectedIndex);
```

but it isn't remove any item.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are setting the DataSource you may not able to modify the items collection. You need to remove the selected item from the Data Source and re bind it.

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    var words = comboBox1.DataSource as List<Word>;
    words.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem as Word);
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    comboBox1.DataSource = words;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
    this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
}
```